# Oracle SQL populating a Time Dimension

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I'm writing a block of code to populate a time dimension in Oracle 11gR2 using SQL Developer

Table Structure

```
KEY Number(8,0)
HRS Varchar2
MINS Varchar2
SECS Varchar2
```

I'm new to PL/SQL - the way i would normally think of doing in pseudo-code would be but the for loops in PL/SQL don't seem to work this way:

```
key = 1
for (hrs=0; hr<=23; hr++)
  {
    for (min=0; min<=59; min++)
     {
       for (sec=0; sec<=59; sec++)
         {
           insert (KEY, tochar(hrs:mins:secs), tochar(hr), tochar(min), tochar(sec))
           SK=+1
         }
     }
  }
```

I've tried this from an answer i found:

```
insert into Dim_TIME 
  (Key,
  TIME_IN24_NAME,
    TIME_HOUR24,
    TIME_MINUTE,
    TIME_SECOND)
select
  to_char(t, 'HH24:MI:SS'),
  to_number(to_char(t, 'HH24'), '00'),
  to_number(to_char(t, 'MI'), '00'),
  to_number(to_char(t, 'SS'), '00')
from (
  select trunc(sysdate) + (level - 1)/86400 as t
  from dual
  connect by level <= 86400
);
```

But not sure how i would increment the key (the column field is not auto-increment).

Any ideas how i could achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: You can use the LEVEL column from you inner query as the key.

Comment: Thanks both these answers worked, i ended up using the LEVEL column.  Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `SEQUENCE` to increment the field `KEY`.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE dim_time_seq;
```

And use it in your code like this,

```
INSERT INTO dim_time 
  (KEY,
  time_in24_name,
  time_hour24,
  time_minute,
  time_second)
SELECT
  dim_time_seq.nextval,   
  to_char(t, 'HH24:MI:SS'),
  to_number(to_char(t, 'HH24'), '00'),
  to_number(to_char(t, 'MI'), '00'),
  to_number(to_char(t, 'SS'), '00')
FROM (
  SELECT trunc(SYSDATE) + (LEVEL - 1)/86400 AS t
  FROM dual
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 86400
);
```